# Mono on Windows (And General Questions)

Tags: c#, windows, linux, mono

I installed MonoDevelop on Linux and wrote a shell GTK+ application.  When I compile and run the application shows up correctly in Linux.  When I move the .exe over to Windows, I get a crash "Windows Not Responding", so there is no stack trace.  Then I figured I had to install Mono For Windows, so I did that, but no luck - I still crash.

More generally, I am having a hard time picturing what is going on here.  Please disabuse me of whatever I get wrong:

1. People who started the Mono project wrote their own compiler (likely from scratch) to compile C# code.  They modeled this after looking at the .NET Framework
2. They also wrote a CLR for their mono implementation of the byte code.  Any architecture that wants to run this code will need the Mono Runtime, as only the Mono Runtime can run the code.

Do I have it right?   Why doesn't my program run?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by your second point you mean "code compiled using mono's C# compiler can only be run by the mono CLR" then the answer is "no".  It can also be run by the MS CLR (assuming all required libraries are installed.)

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but did you start the program directly though Mono? E.g. `mono myprogram.exe`

Comment: @Foole - So if it can run on the MS CLR, then why do I need to open my project in Mono in Windows in the first place?  Why can't I just open it like I would a regular exe, if the bytecode is compatible with the MS CLR.

Comment: @Kevin - Not a dumb question at all - That is what I was doing wrong.  I was just double clicking the .exe in Windows thinking it should "know" to open it with the CLR - I don't really get why that is not correct thinking.  Any insight?  Thanks.

Comment: my guess is that you do not have the required libraries installed under MS.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things stand out to me:

1. GTK+.  GTK isn't part of windows or mono on windows by default.  You must install it separately.
2. Shell Application.  That means something special in the windows world (an app that runs as part of (extends) the windows desktop shell, rather than as it's own program), and I wouldn't be at all surprised to hear that these don't work cross platform very well or even at all. I'd assume you mean "Console Application" instead, but then why the need for GTK+?
3. Mono. Make sure you invoke the program using mono. Just because mono is installed doesn't mean that's how your program will run vs Microsoft's own .Net implementation.

Comment: Couple of clarifications to this - Mono includes GTK# and GTK+, so invoking the app using Mono should work. However, the app can be run under .NET too if you install "GTK# for .NET" from the Mono download page (which includes GTK+).

Comment: I wasn't doing this: Mono. Make sure you invoke the program using mono. Just because mono is installed doesn't mean that's how your program will run vs Microsoft's own .Net implementation.

Why do I need to do this?  If it is just generic CLR code, why wouldn't it run correctly regardless?  I have a fundamental misunderstanding of something.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @skaz - you built it using some mono-specific features (gtk) that aren't part of .Net, so running it via .Net didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I'm only vaguely familiar with Mono myself but I -think- there is an analyzer tool that will show possible portability issues.  If you run through that does it show any issues?

Comment: The Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA) (http://mono-project.com/MoMA) is aimed at people porting Windows based programs *to* mono.  I don't think it applies to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you also check.

Is mono installer contains GTK# libraries.

If yes, check that is the assemblies are in GAC. The assemebiles names be gtk-sharp.dll, gdk-sharp.dll

If no, copy the referenced assemblies in your bin directory. you can see that in your mono develop project.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you wrote a GTK# application. In that case, to run it on Windows, you need to make sure you install "GTK# for .NET" from the [Mono Downloads page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can capture a crash dump and see what causes the crash. For example, use WinDbg to execute this application.

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx